# StackView Content alignment

Tags: ios, swift, stackview

I am working on Stackview and adding two labels , I want to adjust position of labels such that the below label should be a bit right side . E.g in UITableViewCell we have one title and second description goes all the way to right along with increasing content in description part.

```
mainStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),    mainStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)

    ]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(mainStackViewConstraints)

    bodyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Results should looks like this in image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoVUr.png)

Comment: While you *can* get what you want, there is really no reason to use a `UIStackView` for laying out two labels.

Comment: yes but I am just playing around with stack views so that's why I posted this question

Answer (score 0):

A vertical `UIStackView` allows Alignment of `Fill` / `Leading` / `Center` / `Trailing`. The image you've shown does not match any of those.

You *could* do that with nested stack views... The "second line" would be a horizontal stack view with a "spacer" view to give you the leading space.

However, unless this is just part of a more complex layout, `UIStackView` is really not the best route.